# Graphic-rich Javascript pie chart library

Tags: javascript, html, pie-chart

Are there any libraries for JavaScript that can create graphic-rich pie-charts without Flash/Silverlight? Something like [this](http://www.visifire.com/silverlight_pie_doughnut_charts_gallery.php).
Thanks.

Comment: Any reason why google-charts isn't sufficient?

Alternatively you could try something that works with `canvas` like this http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/snazzy-animated-pie-chart-html5-jquery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/):

[image: chart]

Comment: Any idea, with what property you can achieve the labels to be on the outside, with a line pointing to the right pie slice?

Answer (score 4):

[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) is another option, it has some nice interactive/dynamic features, and the appearance is customisable.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](http://www.artetics.com/Articles/using-various-javascript-libraries-to-create-pie-chart)

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [JS Charts](http://www.jscharts.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

D3.js library can do this and a lot more
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki

See [pie chart example](http://blog.stephenboak.com/2011/08/07/easy-as-a-pie.html)

Also [other examples](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) of d3.js possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Google Chart Tools - http://code.google.com/apis/chart/